# Translate R-code into Python code - Unique timestamp values differ by a lot

Tags: python, r, duplicates

My data frame has the columns

```
DOMAINNAME                   object
CUSTOMERNUMBER                int64
CREDITCHECKSOURCE            object
RESULTTEXT                   object
RESULTCODE                   object
FUNCTION                     object
LASTMODIFIED         datetime64[ns]
APPROVEDAMOUNT              float64
ISANONYMIZED                 object
SALESBRAND                   object
COUNTRY                      object
DATE                 datetime64[ns]
DAY                           int64
MONTH                         int64
WEEK                         UInt32
YEAR                          int64
dtype: object
```

where 'DATE' is a datetime like this `'2024-01-08 15:32:07'`. Originally, the unique count for the `'DATE'`-column of the original dataframe is 296723. After the same data frame is passed to the R-code and Python-code below the counts are suddenly 293673 and 280531. I can't figure out why this discrepancy occurs.

I have the dplyr code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  select(-RESULTCODE) %>% 
  filter(RESULTTEXT == "APPROVED" | RESULTTEXT == "DENIED", !is.na(FUNCTION), SALESBRAND != "Stayhard") %>% 
  distinct(across(-DATE), .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select( -CUSTOMERNUMBER )
```

and the corresponding Python code:

```
def filter_transform_alternative(df):
   df_filtered = df[(df['RESULTTEXT'].isin(["APPROVED", "DENIED"])) & 
                     df['FUNCTION'].notna() & 
                    (df['SALESBRAND'] != "Stayhard")]
        
   df_filtered = df_filtered.drop(columns=['CUSTOMERNUMBER'])
        
   cols_for_dupes = [col for col in df_filtered.columns if col not in ['DATE', 'CUSTOMERNUMBER']]
   df_filtered['unique_id'] = df_filtered[cols_for_dupes].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)
        
   df_filtered['is_dupe'] = df_filtered.duplicated(subset='unique_id', keep='first')
   
   df_no_duplicates = df_filtered[df_filtered['is_dupe'] == False].drop(columns=['unique_id', 'is_dupe'])

   return df_no_duplicates
```

Below is a sample data set for reproducibility

```
 DOMAINNAME  CUSTOMERNUMBER CREDITCHECKSOURCE RESULTTEXT  \
0         Ellos-EllosNO      1246087421       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
1         Ellos-EllosSE      1246087439       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
2   Homeroom-HomeroomSE      1244949952       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
3         Ellos-EllosSE       534334891       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
4         Jotex-JotexSE      1246087165       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
5   Homeroom-HomeroomNO      1246087298       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
6         Jotex-JotexDK      1246087207       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
7         Ellos-EllosNO      1246086639       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
8         Ellos-EllosSE       936355635       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
9         Jotex-JotexSE       646132969       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
10        Jotex-JotexNO       943056952       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
11        Ellos-EllosSE      3169943333       MULTIUPPLYS     DENIED   
12        Jotex-JotexNO      1246086944       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
13        Ellos-EllosSE      1245979081       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
14        Ellos-EllosFI      1246086878       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
15        Ellos-EllosSE       936355635       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
16        Ellos-EllosSE      1246074783       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
17  Homeroom-HomeroomSE      1145457782       MULTIUPPLYS     DENIED   
18        Ellos-EllosSE      1246086803       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   
19        Ellos-EllosNO      1245818248       MULTIUPPLYS   APPROVED   

   RESULTCODE FUNCTION        LASTMODIFIED  APPROVEDAMOUNT ISANONYMIZED  \
0         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:32:07          2999.0          nan   
1         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:31:34          4045.0          nan   
2         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:26:49           198.0          nan   
3         nan    LIMIT 2024-01-08 15:26:47         21407.0          nan   
4         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:26:45          9099.0          nan   
5         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:24:45           328.0          nan   
6         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:23:34           641.0          nan   
7         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:22:17          1438.0          nan   
8         nan    LIMIT 2024-01-08 15:20:57         17600.0          nan   
9         nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:20:41           348.0          nan   
10        nan    LIMIT 2024-01-08 15:19:03          7448.0          nan   
11        nan    LIMIT 2024-01-08 15:15:49             0.0          nan   
12        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:15:35          5489.0          nan   
13        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:13:46           603.0          nan   
14        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:12:54           399.0          nan   
15        nan    LIMIT 2024-01-08 15:11:02         13711.0          nan   
16        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:09:54           520.0          nan   
17        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:09:08             0.0          nan   
18        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:09:05           614.0          nan   
19        nan   CREDIT 2024-01-08 15:04:38           885.0          nan   

   SALESBRAND COUNTRY                DATE  DAY  MONTH  WEEK  YEAR  
0       Ellos      NO 2024-01-08 15:32:07    8      1     2  2024  
1       Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:31:34    8      1     2  2024  
2    Homeroom      SE 2024-01-08 15:26:49    8      1     2  2024  
3       Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:26:47    8      1     2  2024  
4       Jotex      SE 2024-01-08 15:26:45    8      1     2  2024  
5    Homeroom      NO 2024-01-08 15:24:45    8      1     2  2024  
6       Jotex      DK 2024-01-08 15:23:34    8      1     2  2024  
7       Ellos      NO 2024-01-08 15:22:17    8      1     2  2024  
8       Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:20:57    8      1     2  2024  
9       Jotex      SE 2024-01-08 15:20:41    8      1     2  2024  
10      Jotex      NO 2024-01-08 15:19:03    8      1     2  2024  
11      Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:15:49    8      1     2  2024  
12      Jotex      NO 2024-01-08 15:15:35    8      1     2  2024  
13      Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:13:46    8      1     2  2024  
14      Ellos      FI 2024-01-08 15:12:54    8      1     2  2024  
15      Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:11:02    8      1     2  2024  
16      Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:09:54    8      1     2  2024  
17   Homeroom      SE 2024-01-08 15:09:08    8      1     2  2024  
18      Ellos      SE 2024-01-08 15:09:05    8      1     2  2024  
19      Ellos      NO 2024-01-08 15:04:38    8      1     2  2024
```

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Comment: @Hoel: Should be the same, except that I'm filtering out on some columns so only the shape of the data frame should differ. In R, distinct(across(-DATE), .keep_all = TRUE) removes duplicates across all columns except DATE, considering each combination of non-DATE values only once, but keeps all other data intact. I think the problem is that I don't know how to replicate this across-function. I could give you the complete .csv data set but I don't think this site allows for data uploads.

Comment: a good [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would show just the 2 single timestamps for comparison.